# NSMutableAttributedString and HTML iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, nsmutablestring

I use `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType` to support HTML tags in UILabel and works fine, but I ran into this problem:

An iFrame in the HTML content doesn't render in my UILabel. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help: https://github.com/rdclark/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML

There is a video example with a Youtube iframe and a HTML5 video tag.